# wordpress $wpbd->get_results not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my query.

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'app_trailer-type'
AND meta_value = 'Bulk Liquid (Tanker)'
AND post_id
IN (

SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'app_additional-hiring-states'
AND meta_value LIKE 'Arkansas (AR)%'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

When I run this query directly in the database one record is returned.

But when I run this query with `$wpdb->results($query);` or  `$wpdb->results($query, OBJECT);` it returns NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$wpdb->results($query);`

to

`$wpdb->get_results($query);`

`get_results()` function returns the entire query result as an array...try it